# Django - Template tags not working properly after form validation

Tags: python, django

I am having a form which takes some value as input, and I am processing the input and returning the required output. Now when I tried to display the output it not displaying on the webpage.

The following is my forms.py:

```
class CompForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comp
        fields = ('inp',)
```

The following is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    form = CompForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    print context
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        ...
        outData = "The values you gave is correct"
        errData = "The values you gave is incorrect"
        print context
        context['outData'] = outData
        context['errData'] = errData
    print context

return render(request, 'comp/index.html', context)
```

The following is my index.html:

```
{% extends "comp/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% if outData %}
        {{ outData.as_p }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if errData %}
        {{ errData.as_p }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In the terminal I am able to get the `outData` and `errData` in the dictionary, but its not getting displayed in the webpage. What might be the mistake? Kindly help.

Comment: `outData` and `errData` are just strings, why are you calling `.as_p` on them? `.as_p` is supposed to be called on forms

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Thanks a lot.. I dint know that... Now it worked... Thank you...

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Okay.. I will mark the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to called the method `as_p` on strings which doesn't make sense.

[`as_p()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) is a helper method on form instances to make it easier to render them in the template so you need:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

you can also use `as_table` and `as_ul`

You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-outputting-html)